# ASP.NET MVC allow input of collection and pass data in post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an entity for an Interview and an entity for InterviewRespondent (the person(s) being interviewed) that is tied to the Interview object via InterviewId.  I should have at least one respondent when creating a new Interview.  I was wondering how I could allow for the input of multiple InterviewRespondent objects without hard-coding the input fields for multiples in the view, and then pass that collection data on to the Create action for my Interview so that when the Interview is posted it adds the Interview to my database, and then loop through the InterviewRespondent list and insert those as well with the newly created InterviewId of the Interview.

Here is my Interview class:

```
public int InterviewId { get; set; }
public string InterviewerId { get; set; }
public int InterviewTypeId { get; set; }
public DateTime InterviewDate { get; set; }        
public string InterviewNoteDetail { get; set; }
```

Here is my InterviewRespondent class:

```
public int InterviewRespondentId { get; set; }
public int InterviewId { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I needed to use a Session variable for storing my List of Respondents.  I thought I could get away with TempData, but it wasn't robust enough.  I added Session via NuGet and then added a couple of lines of code in my Startup.cs file in ConfigureServices:

```
//Session variable
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession();
```

And in Configure:

```
//Session variable
app.UseSession();
```

I added a class to my project called SessionExtensions for getting and setting my Session variable:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void SetObjectAsJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);

        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

I am using $ajax post in my View for adding a Respondent on a button click:

```
$('#uxAddRespondent').click(function () {

        var fname = $('#uxFirstName').val();
        var lname = $('#uxLastName').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("AddRespondent", "Interview")',
            data: { firstName: fname, lastName: lname },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {

                    //Clear the inputs
                    $("#uxFirstName").val('');
                    $("#uxLastName").val('');

                    //Unhide the submit button and the Respondents div
                    $("#uxCancel").removeClass('offset-9');
                    $("#uxCancel").addClass('offset-6');
                    $("#uxSubmit").removeClass('d-none');
                    $("#uxRespondentsDiv").removeClass('d-none');

                    createRespondentTable(data.respondentList);                      
                }
                else {
                    $("<div title='Respondent Name'><span class='text-danger'>Invalid input.<br />Both First and Last Name must contain 2-50 characters.</span></div>").dialog();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I have a JS function for dynamically creating a table of my Respondents:

```
function createRespondentTable(data) {
        //Clear the table content
        $("#uxRespondentTable").empty();

        //Create table content
        var tablecontent = "<table class='table table-hover'>";

        $.each(data, function (index, item) {

            tablecontent += "<tr><td>" + item.interviewRespondentFirstName + " " +
                item.interviewRespondentLastName + "</td>" +
                "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary'" +
                "id='removeRespondent_" + index + "'>Remove</button></td></tr>";
        });

        tablecontent += "</table>";

        $("#uxRespondentTable").append(tablecontent);
    }
```

Here is my code in my Controller for AddRespondent:

```
public JsonResult AddRespondent(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        if (firstName != null && firstName.Length > 1 && lastName != null && lastName.Length > 1)
        {
            var model = new InterviewRespondentViewModel
            {
                InterviewRespondentFirstName = firstName,
                InterviewRespondentLastName = lastName
            };

            var respondentList =
                HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<List<InterviewRespondentViewModel>>("InterviewRespondents");

            if (respondentList == null)
            {
                List<InterviewRespondentViewModel> respList = new List<InterviewRespondentViewModel>();
                respList.Add(model);
                HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("InterviewRespondents", respList);
            }
            else
            {
                respondentList.Add(model);
                HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("InterviewRespondents", respondentList);
            }

            var getRespList = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<List<InterviewRespondentViewModel>>("InterviewRespondents");

            ViewBag.HasRespondent = true;

            return Json(new
            {
                success = true,
                respondentList = getRespList
            });
        }
        return Json(new
        {
            success = false
        });
    }
```

And finally in my Controller once I create the Interview I then loop through the Respondents from the Session variable and create them with the proper InterviewId:

```
_repository.PostInterview(newInterview);

model.InterviewRespondentList = GetInterviewRespondents();

//Add InterviewRespondent
foreach (var respondent in model.InterviewRespondentList)
{
    respondent.InterviewId = newInterview.InterviewId;
    _repository.PostInterviewRespondent(respondent);
}
```

Here is my helper method for GetInterviewRespondents():

```
    private List<InterviewRespondent> GetInterviewRespondents()
    {
        //Get InterviewRespondent List
        var respondentList =
                HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<List<InterviewRespondentViewModel>>("InterviewRespondents");

        //Convert the Respondents from Session "InterviewRespondents" into InterviewRespondent

        List<InterviewRespondent> respondents = new List<InterviewRespondent>();

        foreach (var respondent in respondentList)
        {
            respondents.Add(new InterviewRespondent
            {
                InterviewRespondentFirstName = respondent.InterviewRespondentFirstName,
                InterviewRespondentLastName = respondent.InterviewRespondentLastName
            });
        }

        return respondents;
    }
```

I also got fancy and allowed for removing Respondents while they were still in the Session variable.

I hope this helps someone that wants to get a collection of objects related to some other main object before creating their main object.